# Is it advisable to try to teach myself double bass?

Tags: classical-music, self-learning, double-bass, lessons

I'm learning bluegrass bass, at the moment, but I really want to eventually play classical music. However, teachers are incredibly expensive and I cannot afford one right now. Should I try to teach myself now or should I wait until I find/can afford a teacher so I don't teach myself bad habits?

I play over 16 other instruments and I only had a teacher for two; piano and organ.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the bowed string instruments are certainly among the easiest to get technically wrong. I tried to learn cello for more than one year before taking lessons (at the age of 16, incidentally), and not much came of it. Even incredible musical polymath [Rob Scallon's cello stuff](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zvxZmm7tmXo&index=1&list=PLjRyh8JaC_eRP55B1RF8WBPElZtJd03XZ), while definitely impressive in a way, is really nothing that could be called good cello playing in a classical sense. So if you eventually want to play classical music, you very likely won't get around some real lessons.

But I agree with Tim: bad habits aren't impossible to get rid of; some of them may hinder you *a bit* longer than if you'd learned it properly straight away, but among the bad habits you'll learn also a couple of good skills automatically, and most importantly get *a rough feeling for the instrument*, so I'm pretty sure it's better to start badly than to not start at all before learning properly.

[image: Landscape (sketch)]

In particular, I do think you can become a decent Bluegrass bassist autodidactically. There certainly are quite a lot good self-taught Rockabilly double bassists around.

Comment: `bowed string instruments are certainly among the easiest` Yay!  `to get technically wrong` ... oh.

Answer (score 2):

You're obviously a seasoned musician, who maybe doesn't even need to pose the question! Teaching yourself will involve finding the notes with the left hand, and I guess for bluegrass plucking the strings, not arco. The notes should be pretty apparent, so no problems there; I'd get started, and later find a teacher to sort out how to bow, which will be needed for the classical stuff. As a current player, go for it. I don't think any 'bad' habits can't be sorted later, but if you're making some good in-tune music, that's nearly going to be there anyway.

Comment: I'm not really a "seasoned" musician; I'm 17, haha. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I taught myself the double bass.  But I did buy a text book and could already play the cello!  There is no way you will play classical music without a good left hand technique ( and there are several to choose from).  I see a lot of blue Grass / rockabilly bass players ( and bass guitarists) moving their whole hand up and down the finger board with their fingers bunched like bananas; in classical !usic there are just too many notes to play too far apart for that to work.  After 30 odd years, I cracked and took a couple of lessons (£40) and got past a big block I'd been stuck at for years.  Worth it now and then just for a heads up. Good luck.